# Hiding elements using ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of items i am getting from backend.
I do not want to show two items in UI.

[image]

I do not want to display Conference and reception in UI.
HTML Code:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let space of space_name">
    <div *ngIf="space">
      <a class="dropdown-item text-light" [routerLink]="['/spaces']"
         routerLinkActive="current"
         [queryParams]="{space_name:space}" data-toggle="collapse"
         data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
         style="background-color: #8d0528;">{{ space | uppercase }}</a>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

TS Code:

```
this.sharedService.getDropdownspace().subscribe(data => {
  this.spaceDropdown = data;
  this.api_data = Object.values(this.spaceDropdown);
  this.space_name = this.api_data[0];
})
```

Please suggest me a approach to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by "two items in UI"? Please add more information to your question.

Comment: Basically i am getting 5 values from backend. But i want to display only 3 out of these 5 values excluding conference and reception

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `array filter` method to do the same. Create a function in your component and use it on the `*ngFor` directive like below.

In your **component** create a function to filter the result.

```js
filter(itemList: space_name[]): space_name[] {
    let result: space_name[] = [];
    result = itemList.filter(item => {
        return (item != "Conference" && item != "Reception")
    });
    return result;
}
```

In your **template file**

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let space of filter(space_name)">
    <div *ngIf="space">
        <a class="dropdown-item text-light" [routerLink]="['/spaces']" routerLinkActive="current" [queryParams]="{space_name:space}" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show" style="background-color: #8d0528;">{{ space | uppercase }}</a>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Code and Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ybdmrL2z/

Comment: This will re-filter the array on every single change-detection cycle.